# Testrpc on ubuntu

Tags: testrpc, ubuntu, php

I have a .php website on my ubuntu virtual machine. I want to start the testrpc in this machine, so I can interract with my smartcontract with this web interface. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a local blockchain on Ubuntu using `ganache-cli` (formerly `testrpc`)

https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli

Comment: Does it do the same?

Comment: Yes. ganache-cli was formerly testrpc.

Answer (score 0):

On your virtual machine open a terminal, install `ganache-cli` using `npm` or `yarn` and then you will are able to run a local in-memory blockchain. More details in the official repo at https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli, under the "install" section

To test that you installed it correctly you should run `ganache-cli --version` and see an output.

As another user pointed out `ganache-cli` used to be `testrpc` .

I also found a more narrative article on Medium that might help you understand what's going on: https://medium.com/shyft-network-media/how-we-use-ganache-and-ganache-cli-11bb94aa2d1